# react - update (componentdidupdate)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've read that it's a good use case to put `componentDidUpdate` logic in `useEffect`. I really don't understand something.

Let's imagine I have a list of books page. and when you click on each of the book, you remove it.

- books can be fetched in `useEffect`.

But where should I write `book removal API call` ? I am thinking like this. I create a function and execute it on removal button's `onClick`. That's it. I don't understand why I should use `useEffect` for this. As a sum up, I think we only use `useEffect` for fetching API when the page loads and for other API calls after that, can be done with `onClick` or something like this.

Can someone enlighten this a little bit ?

Comment: It sounds to me like you got it right. `useEffect` can be used to fetch the API and with defined dependencies, you can control when the API should be called. Fetching the API within a `useEffect` and deleting `onClick` is perfectly fine. It's possible to move the `removeBook` API call inside a `useEffect` but would require more than button `onClick`. 
May I ask why you originally wanted the logic inside the useEffect?

Comment: No, you don't have to use `useEffect` to execute your book removal API call. Rather you can use `useCallback` hook for your `onClick` event to optimize your code.